# Combining multiple dataframes which may or may not exist at particular iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running a code inside a for loop.

For each iteration, I have multiple dataframes df1, df2, df3, df4.... which i have to combine and create a final dataframe df_final. Each of those dataframes are preceded by if statement so it is conditional if the dataframe may be generated

Now due to multiple conditions there is a possibility that any or all of the individuals dataframes might not generate.

How do i combine them without worrying if the individuals dataframes have been generated or not?

I tried using try and except but then for each dataframe i cannot provide a condition since there are lots of them. Is there a easier way to do it?

Current erorr:

```
df_final = df1.append([df2, df3, df4])

NameError: name 'df2' is not defined
```

By default i should always get `df_final = df1` in case none of the other dataframes are generated since df1 will always be there.

Note: I have used try and except for error handling but since the number of dataframes is huge it just doesn't seem practical since try block is executed only once

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output so that we have an idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize you final dataframe:

```
df_final = df1
```

And then use a loop:

```
for df_temp in [df2, df3, df4]:
    try:
         df_final = df_final.append(df_temp)
    except:
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You may initially set your variables as `None`

```
df2 = df3 = df4 = ... = None

#Your normal code with your conditions goes here...
```

and then do :

```
df_final = df1.append([x for x in [df2, df3, df4] if x != None])
```